# Can the flair API's JSON feed not be affected by the April Fools'?

Tags: bug, status-completed, flair, unicorns, json

While I have no problems with the site changing everyone's avatar with Unicorns, doing the same with the Flair API's has consequences extending outside Stack Overflow which has hit me hard today.

Is is possible next year to exclude the Flair API from any and all April Fools' jokes? I think that a small and modest feature request that won't cause any lost of functionality.

**EDIT:** Actually, only the JSON feed seem affected by this problem. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/131377.json

**EDIT 2:** I would really appreciate to have an official response as to if this will reoccur next year.

Comment: The Flair API *is* excluded, as far as I know -- at least [it's supposed to be](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44968/horrendous-unicorn-bug/44970#44970).

Comment: I see a gravatar: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/131377.html

Comment: Okay, +1: There's a unicorn in your JSON. Jeff must have missed that one.

Comment: Hit you hard? Surely tolerance of April 1 is mostly universal?

Comment: @In soviet russia, tolerance hits you!

Answer (score 1):

My Win7 (actually Vista) desktop gadget which at least *should* use the gravatar Flair API is showing me as a nice poison-green unicorn. Doesn't cause issues to me but I can see what the annoyance is if there's someone without the intelligence to realize what day today is and how childish we software developers really are.

Comment: Who are you calling a developer??

Comment: YOU are a developer times two!

Answer (score 0):

Cannot reproduce - my flair uses the gravatar avatars, yours should too:

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair

Please link to a website showing your (or anyone else's) flair so we can figure out what's wrong.

Comment: The JSON feed is affacted: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/flair/131377.json

Comment: @Andrew - Ah!  This is the problem then.